# Match any special characters (including underscore, but not space) that are not letters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match any special characters that are not numbers or letters (that people use to write words). I want to include underscore because underscore is neither a number nor a letter that is used in words. But I do not want to include space.

In short, I want to match everyone below except the last two.

```
12345_678
12345*678
12345-678
12345&678
12345－678
12345あ678
12345 678
```

I could not use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` because it does not include non-Latin letters such as Japanese. `\d+(\W|_)\d+` got the unwanted space. What would be the best regular expression for this?

Comment: It should also match `12345－678` (space dash space)?

Comment: I am not quite sure i understand you correctly, but this could perhaps do what you want: `([^\w ]|_)` (Read as an alternation of either "not an alphanumeric nor space" or an "underscore")

Comment: Try `@"\d+[^\w\s]\d+"` or `@"^\d+[^\w\s]\d+$"`

Comment: Isn't `[^\w]` the same as `\W`?

Comment: Note that i did not write `[^\w]`. I wrote `[^\w ]` (there is a space after the w). You might perhaps use `[^\w\s]` instead, as this would also cover other white-spaces such as tab characters...

Comment: Ah, that seems to work. I did not notice the space. Thank you for the tip, `elgonzo`.

Comment: Do you want to match them as separate strings? Or are you extracting the substrings matching this pattern?

Comment: `12345－678`  <= \uFF0D －FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS ?

Comment: This `\pP(?<=[\x00-\x7e])` or this `[!"#%&'()*,\-./:;?@[\]_{}]` should work. https://regex101.com/r/ADSPAg/1

Comment: `－` is a special character in the Korean character set. I just wanted some example of a special character that is not on the English keyboard.

Comment: Then you want `\pP`

Comment: The `[\p{P}\p{S}]` pattern is basically an equivalent of `[^\w\s]`.

Comment: @elgonzo I think you can post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match any character that is neither an alphanumeric character (including characters of different alphabets such as those used in Japan or Korea) nor a space.

```
([^\w ]|_)
```

Note the alteration explicitly matching the underscore character, which is necessary since the underscore is part of the \w character class and thus would not be matched by `[^\w ]` alone. (Also note that the pattern possesses a space character after \w)

If not just simple space characters but any other white-space characters (such as the tab character, for example) should be excluded from the match, too, then the following slightly modified pattern might be more appropriate:

```
([^\w\s]|_)
```

([See here for an example of the latter pattern in action on regexstorm.net, including Hiragana and Hangul characters](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5e%5cw%5cs%5d%7c_%29&i=12345_678%0d%0a12345*678%0d%0a12345-678%0d%0a12345%26678%0d%0a12345%ef%bc%8d678%0d%0a12345%e3%81%82678%0d%0a12345+678%0d%0a12345%e3%85%a1678%0d%0a12345%e3%85%8b678))

Answer (score 0):

Use the following which also ignores Japanese letters:

```
[^a-zA-Z\d\s぀-ゟ゠-ヿ一-龯]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Unicode Character Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-unicode-general-categories). It seems that you need to match for **Symbols** and **Punctuation**.

```
var regexPattern = @"[\p{S}\p{P}]";
```

Symbols include +, -, =, <, $, ^, ¦, § etc

Punctuation include _, —, (, {, ", », !, ?, #, * etc